# Branch io: fallback to AppGallery on Huawei devices

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Tell me if branch io supports fallback to AppGallery on Huawei devices without Google Play services? Now on such a device, a browser opens for me, and redirects to Google Play page of my app. Device - Huawei P40 Lite E Android 10.

By documentation branch io supports such market: https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#default-link-behavior

But there isn't any property to configure such function on branch io dashboard.

How can I check fallbacks on Huawei devices? How do I configure this functionality?

[image]

Here is my configuration:
[image]

Comment: It also depends on the platform. Can you try from messaging or Notes application?

Comment: @KartikShandilya same on other apps such as Notes

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using App Linking. The Unified Linking function allows you to configure links on the AppGallery and Google Play details pages at the same time. Different phones can automatically switch to the corresponding app store.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-unifiedlinking-0000001070790553

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is Branch io support answer:

> Thank you for contacting Branch Support.
>
> Branch links will open the default app store on the device. On devices
> where Huawei App Gallery is the default app store it will be opened to
> download the app.
>
> If you want to try opening the Huwaei app market even when there is a
> different default app store, you can try entering the App link in the
> format https://appmarket://details?id=com.xx.xx
>
> Once the app is installed there is no change in the functionality due
> to the source of app install.

UPD 08.02.2021 second answer:

> They are two methods on how to use a single link which works on both
> Google Play Store and Huawei App Gallery
>
> Method 1 -
>
> Set the Custom URL to point to your app on the Huawei App Gallery, on
> the Configuration page. And set the $android_url parameter for all
> links to the app on Google Play Store.
>
> In this case on Huawei devices the link will redirect the users to the
> Huawei App Gallery when the app is not installed. And on other Android
> devices as the link will not be available, the fallback url set by
> $android_url will kick in, opening the Google Play Store.
>
> Method 2 -
>
> Choose your app from the Google Play Store on the Configuration page.
> If you have any specific links targeting Huawei users, then change the
> Default Redirect for those links to the Web URL of your app on the
> Huawei App Gallery.
>
> Do let me know if this helps.

UPD 09.02.2021

> On the link kindly use the Default Redirect for Android as well.
>
> The default in this case would be the Huawei App Gallery link to your
> app.
>
> On the link data page can you add key -  $fallback_url
>
> value - The play store link to your app
>
> After making the changes on the link, please test the link on both
> Android and Huawei devices at least after an hour or two as the link
> level changes sometimes take a while to reflect.

UPD 07.04.2021

> We had another round of discussion with the Product team on this
> issue, and they mentioned that the fallback to Huawei app gallery is
> not supported anymore.
>
> They have not provided us with the exact details, but they seem to
> have been changes on the OS level on Huawei devices which has broken
> the functionality and which we have been unable to fix due to certain
> limitations.
>
> Unfortunately this flow is not supported at the moment.
>
> I do apologise for any impact this might have on your link, but it
> does look like we do not have any solutions for this matter at the
> moment.

Comment: Then there's no way to integrate branch io with huawei gallery?
Have you tried any other service?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following:

The typical link format of the application details page on Huawei AppGallery is:
https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/appDetail? pkgName=**packagename**&channelId=**channelid**&referrer=**referrer**&detailType=0&calltype=AGDLINK

Parameter description:

**Packagename**: required, the package name to be popularized and applied, such as com.huawei.gamebox ..

**Channelid**: It is recommended to fill in. To improve the channel identification degree of data analysis, it is recommended to fill in the designated identification number for each channel. If it is not filled in, the system will automatically read the package name of the source media, but the package name cannot be obtained by jumping through the webpage or offline QR code.

**Referrer**: not required; if not, it will be blank by default. This parameter refers to the secondary channel number. When links are posted on multiple pages (scenes) of the same media, the specific location effect of the media can be identified by the secondary channel number.

DetailType=0&calltype=AGDLINK: basic parameter, which cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thank you! But the main problem that I am not involve to creating such links. Branch io service is generating link and redirect user to market. And problem is in my case brach io not redirect me to AppGallery on Huawei device.

Comment: According to the documents of Branch and the specific use of their console, I found that Branch does not support pulling up the AppGallery directly, but it is implemented through fallback_URL. this is doc of branch: https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#your-app-is-not-installed

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add a fallback field to the link that I open? Or I can configure it somewhere in the branch dashboard?