# Branch io: how should I configure link, in order to open default app market when user click the link of an Android App which haven't been installed?

Tags: branch.io

in Branch dashboard, I must configure links like this below:
[Branch links Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uTFt.png)
from that, you can see that I must configure a specific address.
However, as I know, some Huawei phones do not support Google Play Store, so if I only configure the Google Play address, it will not be available on Huawei phones. However, if I configure only the Huawei AppGallery address, it will not be available on non-Huawei phones. Is there an automatic way to judge?

Comment: I have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048194/branch-io-fallback-to-appgallery-on-huawei-devices?noredirect=1#comment116848518_66048194
You can write to brach support. They have a great support.

Comment: @AndrewEvtukhov I tried method1, but I found that Custom URL I set on Configuration page is same as $android_url parameter set by api. This means that only one link can be set for android.

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here:

By default, the Branch links will redirect to the Huawei app gallery without any special configuration. This is since both google and Huawei use the same URI scheme(market://details) to launch the store. On Huawei devices with no PlayStore, Branch links will fire the same URI scheme and the user is routed to Huawei App Gallery.

Comment: Did you see my picture? You say that the default value can be opened, but how do I configure it on the Branch console? When I try to generat  links, the next step cannot be performed without configuration like picture above.

Comment: Now if I use 'Google Play Search' on Branch,  the link will lead me to the browser and show me Google Play. It doesn't open Huawei AppGallery like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Huawei App Linking. The Unified Linking function allows you to configure links on the AppGallery and Google Play details pages at the same time. Different phones can automatically switch to the corresponding app store.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-unifiedlinking-0000001070790553

[image]