# Branch IO Huawei Integration

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, huawei-mobile-services, branch.io

i have an app integranted with firebase services, including Dynamic links

Now i have made the integration with huawei and already published in app Gallery, but now i have troubles with deep links

I have tried things like use deeplink of huawei inside deeplink of firebase and vice versa, but did't work

Now i'm trying Branch.io and works for playstore and App Store, but i can't figure out how to make work with huawei gallery

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059299/11891580), and i guess is not possible wat i want, i'll be grateful for any helpful answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may can use [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/App-linking/?ha_source=hms1).

[image]

After you set an AppGallery link:

1 If an Android user has installed AppGallery, the user will be redirected to the AppGallery link preferentially.

2 If an Android user has not installed AppGallery, the user will be redirected to the link for other Android users preferentially.

- If you do not set an AppGallery link, the user will be redirected to the link for other Android users preferentially.
- If you do not set an AppGallery link or the link for other Android users, the user will be redirected to the default link.

For more details, pls kindly refer to [this Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-unifiedlinking-0000001070790553).

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I have read de docs, but app linking only works in android with huawei services, and also y have an api rest to create the deep link, and app linking is not supported for Node js or something similar

Comment: hi@Jonathan Ixcayau, App Linking does not depend on Huawei services and can be used on non-Huawei devices and iOS devices.

Comment: And REST APIs for App Linking are under development and are planned to be released at the end of September.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have been trying app linking and it really works <3

Comment: Hi Shirley, could you give me more information about the release date?

Comment: hi@Jonathan Ixcayau, According to the team, it is planned to be released at the end of September. Please follow the official website for the specific release date.